# Storing XML node values with R's xmlEventParse for filtered output

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I have a huge xml file (260mb) with tons of information looking like this:

Example:

```
<mydocument>
<POSITIONS EventTime="2012-09-29T20:31:21" InternalMatchId="0000T0">
<FrameSet GameSection="1sthalf" Match="0000T0" Club="REFEREE" Object="00011D">
<Frame N="0" T="2012-09-29T18:31:21" X="-0.1158" Y="0.2347" S="1.27" />
<Frame N="1" T="2012-09-29T18:31:21" X="-0.1146" Y="0.2351" S="1.3" />
<Frame N="2" T="2012-09-29T18:31:21" X="-0.1134" Y="0.2356" S="1.33" />
</FrameSet>
<FrameSet GameSection="2ndhalf" Match="0000T0" Club="REFEREE" Object="00011D">
<Frame N="0" T="2012-09-29T18:31:21" X="-0.1158" Y="0.2347" S="1.27" />
<Frame N="1" T="2012-09-29T18:31:21.196" X="-0.1146" Y="0.2351" S="1.3" />
<Frame N="2" T="2012-09-29T18:31:21.243" X="-0.1134" Y="0.2356" S="1.33" />
</FrameSet>
</POSITIONS>
</mydocument>
```

there are around 40 different FrameSet nodes, each with a different `GameSection="..."` and `Object="..."`.

I would love to extract the information of the `<Frame>` nodes into a `list` object but I cannot load the whole xml file because it is too large. Is there any way, I can use the `xmlEventParse` function to filter for a specific *GameSection* and a specific *Object* and get all the information from the corresponding `<Frame>` elements?

Comment: You could try `xpathApply`. If you need more help, you have to provide an [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: i added some example content of the file. to use xpathApply, I would have to load the xml file first, right? or could i do this on the run?

Answer (score 8):

It might be that the 'internal' representation is not that large

```
xml = xmlTreeParse("file.xml", useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

and then xpath will definitely be your best bet. If that doesn't work, you'll need to get your head around closures. I'm going to aim for the `branches` argument of `xmlEventParse`, which allows a hybrid event parsing to iterate through the file, coupled with DOM parsing on each node. Here's a function that returns a list of functions.

```
branchFactory <-
    function()
{
    env <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())   # safety

    FrameSet <- function(elt) {
        id <- paste(xmlAttrs(elt), collapse=":")
        env[[id]] <- xpathSApply(elt, "//Frame", xmlAttrs)
    }

    get <- function() env

    list(get=get, FrameSet=FrameSet)
}
```

Inside this function we're going to create a place to store our results as we iterate through the file. This could be a list, but it'll be better to use an environment. This will allow us to insert new results without copying all the results that we've already inserted. So here's our environment:

```
    env <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
```

we use the `parent` argument as a measure of safety, even if it's not relevant in our present case. Now we define a function that will be invoked whenever a "FrameSet" node is encountered

```
    FrameSet <- function(elt) {
        id <- paste(xmlAttrs(elt), collapse=":")
        env[[id]] <- xpathSApply(elt, "//Frame", xmlAttrs)
    }
```

It turns out that, when we use the `branches` argument, the `xmlEventParse` will have arranged to parse the entire node into an object that we can manipulate via the DOM, e.g., using `xlmAttrs` and `xpathSApply`. The first line of this function creates a unique identifier for this frame set (? maybe that's not the case for the full data set? You'll need a unique identifier). we then parse the "//Frame" part of the element, and store that in our environment. Storing the result is trickier than it looks -- we're assigning to a variable called `env`. `env` doesn't exist in the body of the FrameSet function, so R uses its lexical scoping rules to search for a variable named `env` in the environment in which the FrameSet function was *defined*. And lo, it finds the `env` that we have already created. This is where we add the result of `xpathSApply` to. That's it for our FrameSet node parser.

We'd also like a convenience function that we can use to retrieve `env`, like this:

```
    get <- function() env
```

Again, this is going to use lexical scoping to find the `env` variable created at the top of `branchFactory`. We end `branchFactory` by returning a list of the functions that we've defined

```
    list(get=get, FrameSet=FrameSet)
```

This too is surprisingly tricky -- we're returning a list of functions. The functions are defined in the environment created when we invoke `branchFactory` and, for lexical scope to work, the environment has to persist. So actually we're returning not only the list of functions, but also, implicitly, the variable `env`. In brief

We're now ready to parse our file. Do this by creating an instance of the branch parser, with it's own unique versions of the `get` and `FrameSet` functions and of the `env` variable created to store results. Then parse the file

```
b <- branchFactory()
xx <- xmlEventParse("file.xml", handlers=list(), branches=b)
```

We can retrieve the results using `b$get()`, and can cast this to a list if that's convenient.

```
> as.list(b$get())
$`1sthalf:0000T0:REFEREE:00011D`
  [,1]                  [,2]                  [,3]                 
N "0"                   "1"                   "2"                  
T "2012-09-29T18:31:21" "2012-09-29T18:31:21" "2012-09-29T18:31:21"
X "-0.1158"             "-0.1146"             "-0.1134"            
Y "0.2347"              "0.2351"              "0.2356"             
S "1.27"                "1.3"                 "1.33"               

$`2ndhalf:0000T0:REFEREE:00011D`
  [,1]                  [,2]                      [,3]                     
N "0"                   "1"                       "2"                      
T "2012-09-29T18:31:21" "2012-09-29T18:31:21.196" "2012-09-29T18:31:21.243"
X "-0.1158"             "-0.1146"                 "-0.1134"                
Y "0.2347"              "0.2351"                  "0.2356"                 
S "1.27"                "1.3"                     "1.33"
```